# You have seen that $ \int_0^{\infty} f(t) e^ {-t}dt $ = $ \int_0^{\infty} f'(t) e^ {-t}dt $ is sometimes true. Find some non-polynomial examples

Tags: calculus

You have seen that

$$
\int_0^{\infty} f(t) e^ {-t}dt 
=
\int_0^{\infty} f'(t) e^ {-t}dt
$$

is true for some functions $f(t)$. Find some non-polynomial examples.

Is this problem meant for me to take the derivative of both sides? I found $\sin(ax)$ for all $a$ works, because the derivative of each integral is $f(x) e^{-x}$ and $f'(x) e^{-x}$ respectively for $x$ approaching infinity, and $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ both are "slower" than $e^x$.

Edit: I changed the integral into

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^{x} f(t) e^ {-t}dt
=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^{x} f'(t) e^ {-t}dt
$$

Then took the derivative of both sides, so I got

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x) e^{-x}  = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f'(x) e^{-x}.$$

It was with this that I saw $f(x)=\sin(ax)$ fits this limit equality, so it would fit the original equation. Thoughts?

Comment: Indeed $$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {\sin (at)e^{ - t} dt}  = \frac{a}{{a^2  + 1}} = \int_0^{ + \infty } {a\cos (at)e^{ - t} dt}  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {(\sin (at))'e^{ - t} dt} .
$$

Comment: If $f(0)=0$ the equality holds for any $f$ provided the integrals converge.

Comment: I'm not sure you completely follow the question. $\int_0^\infty f(t)e^{-t}dt$ and $\int_0^\infty f'(t)e^{-t}dt$ are numbers, not functions, so it doesn't really make sense to take their derivatives. You are looking for functions $f$ such that the numbers are the same. What integration technique allows you to relate integrals containing $f(t)$ to integrals containing $f'(t)$?

Comment: It's true $f(x) = \sin(ax)$ works, but I don't understand your reasoning at all.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc You also need that $\lim_{t\to \infty}f(t)e^{-t}$ exists and is $0$.

Comment: @Gary Right, but there is still a lot of freedom.

Comment: @Knocker379 You cannot differentiate with respect to $x$ because $x\to \infty$. Your final reasoning does not make any sense. The same reasoning would work with $\cos(ax)$ but the original problem is not satisfied by $f(x)=\cos(ax)$.

Comment: @Jason Chain rule is the only one I could see containing f(t) and f'(t)

Comment: @Knocker379 The answer to Jason's question is *integration by parts*. See the answer by Ryszard Szwarc below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $ f(x)$ is differentiable, bounded and $f(0)=0.$ Then the integration by parts gives $$\int\limits_0^A f'(x)e^{-x}\,dx = f(x)e^{-x}\mid_0^A+\int\limits_0^Af(x)e^{-x}\,dx$$ RHS is convergent, when $A\to \infty,$ hence we obtain $$\int\limits_0^\infty f'(x)e^{-x}\,dx=\int\limits_0^\infty f(x)e^{-x}\,dx$$

Comment: You may assume that both integrals exist. Otherwise, something like $f(t)=\sin(te^{t^2})$ would be a counterexample.

Comment: @Gary It is not a counterexample and no additional assumptions are necessary. I have re-edited the answer to make it clear.

Comment: Ok, it is clear now.